# Tools for documentations

Tags: 12.04, software-recommendation

I am trying to do good documentation of products list. Like creating a software test documentation with test id, test name, etc.

Can you recommend a good, platform independent etc. software available in Ubuntu 12.04?

Of course, can you give one or two sentences to give reason why you recommend it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Natural Docs is an open-source documentation generator for multiple
>   programming languages.  You document your code in a natural syntax
>   that reads like plain English.  Natural Docs then scans your code and
>   builds high-quality HTML documentation from it.

To download it [Click here](http://naturaldocs.org/download.html)

Also Wikipedia has a comprehensive list of documentation generators with comparison.

[Comparison of documentation generators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_documentation_generators)

Also you can check this out [Other Documentation Tools](http://www.python.org/community/sigs/current/doc-sig/otherlangs/)

Sources: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_documentation_generators), and [Natural Docs](http://naturaldocs.org/about.html)

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about [Latex](http://www.latex-project.org/)?
There are different kinds of Latex software for Ubuntu. You could try out:
1. [Kile](http://kile.sourceforge.net/) 
2. [Texmaker](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/)
3. [Lyx](http://www.lyx.org/)

But have a look into Latex. I'm sure it can help you out, and maybe become a good friend of yours.